# How to resize the image?

Tags: images, image-manipulation

What is wrong with this signature of mine? For this set of instructions? I have resized the image well enough but where did I go wrong? How am I supposed to edit the image?

https://ibpsonline.ibps.in/sbijascapr21/uploads/loadpdf.php?file=k7m5p+fQ15e7vNTdwtzIy9nYnJZ9sc/KYaao1bWrpok=&t=1LHArOLA2di0yczXwNDa083LmNWypw==#toolbar=0&navpanes=0

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instructions says

> Dimensions 140 x 60 pixels (preferred) Size of file should be between 10 kb – 20kb for signature and left thumb impression. For hand written declaration size of file should be 20kb- 50kb.

The image you posted is 560 x 160 pixels, so is too large.

The simplest way to shrink this is using Paint (Windows) and use the "Resize" option in the toolbar and specify 140px in the Horizontal plane.

[image]

Comment: How do I change file size?